# Setting path for rails 3.2.8 in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, path, rvm

I am completely new to Ubuntu, I am trying to complete my installation of Ruby On Rails, so far I have installed both Ruby 1.9.3 and set it as the default and I installed Rails 3.2.8, when I open a new terminal it doesn't recognise my Rails install and I understand from looking for help that I need to set a path in a bashrc file.

2 problems I have is trying to understand what my path is and how I input this to the bashrc file(how can I find the file or do I use a command in the terminal to do set the path)

Here is the location of my Ruby and Rails install

```
andrew@andrew-laptop:~$ sudo updatedb
[sudo] password for andrew: 
andrew@andrew-laptop:~$ locate rails|grep -e "bin/rails$"
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/rails
/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.8/bin/rails
```

I tried this but nothing changed

```
andrew@andrew-laptop:~$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/andrew/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin
```

Comment: Even though Rails is a development tool your problems are basic Unix concepts adressed in many tutorials and books.

Comment: @madth3 You're almost correct, however in this instance I think he failed to install `rvm` correctly. The `rvm` environment should be loaded automatically by the `bashrc` file upon login. For some reason it is not doing so in this case. There should be no need to mess with the path. You could use `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` to manually load `rvm` in the new shell: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: Btw. what does "it doesn't recognize my Rails install mean"? Please add the exact error message to the question.

Comment: Thanks, sourcing to rvm works in a new window, I will stick with using Rails this way for now until I get my head around using linux a bit more. Do you know where my installation of RVM might have gone wrong or what would be a way of not having to source to RVM everytime I open a new terminal? This is the installation guide I followed http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: This was the response I was getting in the terminal when I didnt source to RVM andrew@andrew-laptop:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * rails
 * ruby-railties-3.2
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>

Comment: This question isn't really suited for SO. I would log onto IRC to chat to some helpful community members: http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat

Comment: This question does display a basic lack of understanding of the OS environment. However, some of community comments here are excellent examples of why breaking into the UNIX environment is so difficult for beginners.

Answer (score 3):

You are on ubuntu so most likely this steps should fix:

1. https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/
2. close and open new terminal window
3. `rvm use 1.9.3 --default --install`
4. `gem install rails`

visit https://rvm.io for more details